# Emulator's hasSystemFeature for GPS and NETWORK always return false?

Tags: android, networking, gps, hardware

The availability of a hardware in Android can be checked by using `hasSystemFeature()`. However when I tried calling `context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS)` and 
`context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_NETWORK)` on an emulator, both command returned false.

This is despite the fact that the emulator has a GPS. What could be the problem? How do I check in an emulator if it has a GPS or NETWORK hardware?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your own latitude and longitude for emulator :
follow this : 
using DDMS

```
->go to your android/tools directory, and launch the DDMS tool
->select the Emulator Control Tab
->fill the Location Controls fields with the longitude and latitude values
->press the Send button
```